# Why does kill not work from script, but does work from terminal?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, kill, dash

I have the following contrived script to illustrate my issue:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -eux
sudo sleep 120 &
spid=$!
sleep 1
sudo kill $spid
wait $!
```

This will print

```
$ ./test.sh 
+ spid=21931
+ sleep 1
+ sudo sleep 120
+ sudo kill 21931
+ wait 21931
```

and then hang on `wait` until the `sleep 120` times out.  However, when I run `sudo kill 21931` from another terminal the sleep process is killed immediately.  I expected the `sudo kill $spid` line in the script to also kill the sleep process immediately.  Why doesn't this work and how do I make this work?

(Might be relevant: I see this behaviour bash 4.3.42 and dash 0.5.7 on Ubuntu 15.10.)

Comment: Just tried the same on an Ubuntu 14.04 machine (bash 4.3.11 / dash 0.5.7), and that gives me the behaviour I would expect: the sudo kill command from the script immediately kills the sleep 120 and the script ends. So, what could be different on Ubuntu 15.10 (or this machine)?

Comment: Just a comment: The `spid` variable will hold the PID of the `sudo` process, not the PID of `sleep`.

Comment: The same with Centos 7.5. The command from the script does not work, but it works from command line. There are 2 pids, `sudo sleep` and `sleep`. `$!` returns the pid of `sudo sleep`. Killing this pid from the script does nothing, killing this exact same pid from command line does kill the command (both `sudo sleep` and `sleep` processes are killed).

Comment: The problem exists in Centos 7.5, and not in Centos 7.6. Just like Ubuntu 15 VS Ubuntu 18.

Answer (score 2):

the reason could be found in [source code](https://github.com/sudo-project/sudo/blob/c4a579cf8a8ba092ea4135c1a1a007f537dcc960/src/exec_nopty.c) of sudo:

```
/*
 * Do not forward signals sent by a process in the command's process
 * group, as we don't want the command to indirectly kill itself.
 * For example, this can happen with some versions of reboot that
 * call kill(-1, SIGTERM) to kill all other processes.
 */
```

Answer (score 1):

The difference could be in the /etc/sudoers file. Maybe your user is allowed to run kill with nopasswd on one machine, but not on the other.

Comment: Interesting thought, but the only difference between the sudoers files was that in one I had `Defaults !tty_tickets` (the 'hanging' 15.10 machine). But after removing the line, the machine still hangs on wait.  (There were no files in /etc/sudoers.d/ on both machines.)

Answer (score 0):

I confirm this strange behaviour occurs as well on Ubuntu 17.10 bash 4.4.12(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu).

I wasn't able to track down the real reason but it seems it has something to do with process signals. By default, `kill` sends out signal `15 – TERM` which stands for a soft kill. However, if I use a hard `9 – KILL`, the sleep process gets immediately killed.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -eux
sudo sleep 120 &
spid=$!
sleep 1
sudo kill -9 $spid
wait $!
```

prints out

```
$ ./test.sh 
+ spid=4342
+ sleep 1
+ sudo sleep 120
+ sudo kill -9 4342
./test.sh: line 6:  4342 Killed                  sudo sleep 120
+ wait 4342
```

Comment: It's the `sudo` that gets killed, not the `sleep`. `sudo` ought to relay the `TERM` signal to `sleep` though.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and landed here. The other answers didn't help. My script was piping IDs into kill along the lines of:

```bsh
echo $some_output | awk '{print $1}' | xargs kill -9
```

This worked from the terminal but not from a script. After finding this answer that said [kill doesn't read PIDs from stdin](https://askubuntu.com/a/712083), I changed the script to this and it fixed the problem:

```bsh
pids=`echo $some_output | awk '{print $1}'`

for p in $pids; do
    echo "Killing $p"
    kill -9 $p
done
```

Hopefully, that helps someone who landed here like I did!

Comment: on a related note: `pkill <name>` and `pidof <name>` were two very helpful commands that I found after writing my script that simplified things a lot.